# DICOM Dump for Visual Studio Codeで文字化けの文字しか見れない

Tags: vscode

[DICOM Dump for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=smikitky.vscode-dicom&ssr=false#overview)の使い方がよくわかりません。

インストールをしてみたいのですが、相変わらず文字化けの文字しか見れません。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 作者のGitHubで聞いてみたらどうでしょう？[Issues - smikitky/vscode-dicom-dump](https://github.com/smikitky/vscode-dicom-dump/issues)

Answer (score 1):

リンク先の下の方にトラブルシューティングが3つ書いてあって、その1つ目と3つ目が以下の様ですが、そういうことで**元々のファイルが標準に準拠していないか破損しているか、データの文字エンコーディングが違うのではないですか？**

> **My DICOM file does not load at all!** : Can you open that file with dicom-parser's online demo? If not, probably your DICOM file is not standard-compliant, and there is little I can do. Some DICOM implementations are tolerant enough to open mildly broken files. Just because you can view your file with  does not mean the file is not corrupted. If you could open the file with the demo above and are still getting an error from this extension, feel free to report as a bug.
>
> **DICOMファイルがまったく読み込まれません！** ：dicom-parserのオンラインデモでそのファイルを開くことができますか？そうでない場合、おそらくDICOMファイルは標準に準拠していないため、私にできることはほとんどありません。一部のDICOM実装は、軽度に破損したファイルを開くのに十分な耐性を備えています。<お気に入りのビューアをここに挿入>でファイルを表示できるからといって、ファイルが破損していないわけではありません。上記のデモでファイルを開くことができ、それでもこの拡張機能からエラーが発生する場合は、バグとして報告してください。
>
> **Patient/institution names are garbled!** : Currently the character encoding support is limited and buggy, and it's partially due to the fact that DICOM uses rare character encodings not supported by iconv-lite. Also note that some DICOM implementations store multibyte strings with a totally wrong encoding (e.g., Japanse SJIS). I'd rather not support all sorts of malformed files "in the wild", but reasonable suggestions and PRs are welcome.
>
> **患者/施設名が文字化けしています！** ：現在、文字エンコーディングのサポートは制限されており、バグがあります。これは、DICOMがiconv-liteでサポートされていないまれな文字エンコーディングを使用しているという事実に一部起因しています。また、一部のDICOM実装では、マルチバイト文字列がまったく間違ったエンコーディング（たとえば、日本のSJIS）で格納されることに注意してください。あらゆる種類の不正なファイルを「荒野で」サポートするのではなく、合理的な提案とPRを歓迎します。